# Images dont align left and right in custom action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to place two images in a custom toolbar: one on the left side and one on the right side. My two images are shown in the middle of the bar and are overlapping.

How do I fix this ? I tried also with android:layout_gravity. But the images are not moving left/right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkgreen"
        app:subtitle="Sub"
        app:title="AndroidlyToolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/minus"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_symbol_button" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the layout and it is working fine
but you can try the linearLayout if that is not  working!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkgreen"
    app:subtitle="Sub"
    app:title="AndroidlyToolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/minus"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_symbol_button" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I added </LinearLayout> because without it it throws an error. But it doesn't help. The minus button stays centered and the plus button will not show.